RIG 600 PRO HX headset has a red light that won't turn off
So I was playing my game with my friends, and I went to go plug my RIG 600 PRO HX headset in while playing, and they said power off, and I went to go plug it back in, but they didn't work. 
Now there's a red light, and it won't go away, and they won't work.

I'd check out their website. They seem to have some videos, maybe it includes troubleshooting,  or if you kept the packaging, maybe there was a manual you can refer to?

Sounds like a very common problem
